# java how to check if CDI is enabled?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

how to check if CDI is enabled in current environment(SE or EE)? If enabled,
CDI should be used to instantiate a class (e.g. Foo), otherwise use new Foo().

```
Foo foo;
if (isCDIEnabled()) {
  // how to get CDI container from current environment
  foo = cdiContainer.select(Foo.class).get();
}
else
   foo = new Foo();
```

How to implement

```
 private boolean isCDIEnabled() {
     // how?
 }
```

Comment: check if `cdiContainer` is `null`?

Comment: no. do not know how to get CDI container.

Comment: Which is the context of the problem? Your code can execute in a CDI and non-CDI enviroment?

Comment: Yes. both CDI and non-CDI. So need to check if CDI is enabled

Answer (score 1):

If you have cdi api in your classpath, try this:

```
    try{
        CDI.current();
    }catch(IllegalStateException e){
        // no cdi available 
    }
```

Comment: Does this work in SE environment?  CDI is not available in SE, right? What is the compile dependencies?

Comment: Works if your SE environment contains the cdi-api jar. The link of the dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.enterprise/cdi-api/1.2. P.S: I pasted the version 1.2. Check the version you're using.

Comment: Compiling works. but adding: runtimeOnly group: 'org.jboss.weld', name: 'weld-core', version: '2.4.8.Final', still got java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access CDI. What is the right CDI provider impl?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access CDI
 at javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.lambda$getCDIProvider$1(CDI.java:88)
 at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
 at javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.getCDIProvider(CDI.java:88)
 at javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.current(CDI.java:64)

Comment: The illegalstateexception will be thrown when the CDI is not available.

Comment: But weld is in the classpath. It should be available.

Comment: But are you running on a Java ee enviroment?